# mysqli_query() null given error

Tags: php, mysqli

What is wrong on these codes? I am very much new to mysqli. I always get this error

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\localhost\path\core.php on line 11
>   Error, query failed!!!

I tested the connection and it is working and connected so I dont understand why I always see this warning and my query failed. I also checked the query and it is correct. Here are my codes:

**configuration.php**

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'xxx'; 
$dbuser = 'xxx';
$dbpass = 'xxx'; 
$dbname = 'xxx'; 

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname) or die ('Error connecting to mysql');

?>
```

**core.php**

```
<?php
require_once('configuration.php');

class Core {
    public $coreTable;
    public $result;
    public $num_rows;

    function Execute($query) {
        $this->result = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die('Error, query failed!!!'); //line 11
        $this->row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows( $this->result );
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: The $conn variable is out of scope, because it is not part of the Core class.

Comment: Use MySQLi as object, even better than procedural style. => `class CoreDatabase extends \MySQLi { ... };`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a variable scope issue. Your `$conn` variable is defined out of the function's scope and it isn't available inside the `Core` class.

As a quick fix, you can change it to a global variable:

```
global $conn;
```

For more information, refer to the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) documentation.

Comment: oh sorry it works now, I defined it on configuration.php instead of inside the function execute. I thought php is the same as in C. thanks.

Comment: Why create a global that can be used in all scopes, why not pass it to necessary functions? Or use the other examples posted above?

Answer (score 3):

You're probably trying to reach a variable outside the Core class. First, you may want to read about [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) here.

Quick and dirty solution is:

Inject `$conn` variable when you instantiating Core class first time.

Add a `__construct() {}` method to Core class:

```
<?php
require_once('configuration.php');

class Core {
    public $connection; // Notice here
    public $coreTable;
    public $result;
    public $num_rows;

    /**
     * Documenting classes and methods is a good practice.
     * Constructor method
     * 
     * @param Resource $conn Mysql connection.
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($conn)
    {
       $this->connection = $conn;
    }

    function Execute($query) {
        $this->result = mysqli_query($this->connection,$query) or die('Error, query failed!!!'); //line 11
        $this->row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows( $this->result );
    }
  }
?>
```

And when you're instantiating your Core class for the first time:

```
$class = new Core($conn); // We are injecting the $conn here
```

Thats it. If it sounds interesting to you, read more about [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) here.

Answer (score 0):

$conn doesnt exist in in the scope you are currently in use

Either pass the connection to the class on creation or use the global variable $conn